# Why does this Pumpkin have Two Different Sides?

Tags: pumpkins

I planted some pumpkin seeds from a fancy (and tasty) pumpkin I bought last year, I think was a glass slipper pumpkin (https://outstandingseed.com/shop/stacking-pumpkins/glass-slipper-f1-pumpkin/).

The resultant pumpkins look odd. The top looks like a proper glass slipper pumpkin (kind of a muted pinky-orange and green). The bottom is almost a gray-white. It started off more white and that part shrunk a bit...I kept thinking the white part would grow smaller, but it just seemed to stop growing.

Is this some condition that happens with pumpkins?  It looks like a ghost pumpkin stitched to a glass slipper pumpkin.

I have two pumpkin plants in the same very large pot - they both have pumpkins that look like this.

[image: Weird Pumpkin - Top (Glass Slipper)]
[image: Weird Pumpkin - Bottom (Ghost Nub)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You grew a **Turban Squash** by accident. But how?

[image: Turban Squash]

Must be an [**F1**](https://en.wikipedia.xn--orgwikif1_hybrid-cz6ie) surprise. With F1 hybrids, two parents produce uniquely desirable offspring for *one generation alone*. A mule is an example (and always a sterile male).
The seeds of the tasty F1 hybrid pumpkin you bought have gone on to reflect one of the original F1 parents—unpredictably.

Seed catalogs may list a cryptic "(F1)" to signal all this, that saving crop seeds in farming tradition will produce unexpected results next season. Heirloom seeds, aside from a fuller taste, do not enter the F1 world of mystery.

Remember. *the gardener plans and Nature improvises*.

Comment: I've just got to say I _love_ this answer and the fact that I went from "what's wrong with my pumpkin" to "surprise it's a Turban" is so much fun. I may keep planting random pumpkin seeds just for the thrill of trying to guess the results.